# Add variable geom_hline to all facets of a barplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a barplot using the ggplot2 library:

```
plot <- qplot(Date, data=cns, 
              geom="bar", binwidth = 1, 
              fill=Type, facets = Name ~ .)
```

Which gives me a faceted barplot, by name.

The first 11 rows of cns looks like:

```
            Name       Date      Type     Days
1           Name 1 2013-03-12 Requested    0
2           Name 1 2013-03-14 Requested    0
3           Name 1 2013-03-19 Requested    0
4           Name 2 2013-03-01 Completed    1
5           Name 2 2013-03-01 Requested    0
6           Name 2 2013-03-07 Completed    3
7           Name 2 2013-03-08 Requested    0
8           Name 2 2013-03-08 Requested    0
9           Name 3 2013-03-08 Completed    0
10          Name 3 2013-03-13 Requested    0
11          Name 3 2013-03-12 Completed    0
```

I would like to add a horizontal line to each facet, with the mean number of days (specific to the facet, or Name).  This is also complicated because the column "Days" has 0s entered for all Type 'Requested', meaning that to get the mean I'm looking for I really want the `mean(cns$Days)/(NROW(cns)/2)`.

I tried:

```
plot + geom_hline(aes(yintercept=(sum(cns$Days)/(NROW(cns)/2))))
```

But, as I sort of expected, it places a horizontal line of the same value in each of the facets.  I would like the line to be facet-specific, if that makes sense.

Can this be done?

Comment: The basic idea would be to make a data frame with the required values, and pass that directly to `geom_hline`. But your description of what you mean by "mean number of days" is very unclear, so I can't really say much beyond that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can make new column in your data frame that contains mean value. I named it as `y.int` and calculated using function `ddply()` from library `plyr`. Here mean value calculated only for the values where `Type` is `Completed` (as `Requested` should be excluded).

```
library(plyr)
cns<-ddply(cns,.(Name),transform,y.int=mean(Days[Type=="Completed"]))
```

Now use `geom_hline()` and new column to add lines to each facet.

```
plot + geom_hline(aes(yintercept=y.int))
```

Comment: By putting the `y.int` into `cns`, and then calling `geom_hline` with that, you will be drawing multiple horizontal lines in each facet (one for each row in `cns` corresponding to that facet). While this may not have a practical effect, in some circumstances it may (transparency, anti-aliaising, plot file size).

Comment: @BrianDiggs +1 Your are right, making of new data frame could be better way.

Answer (score 3):

A variant on [Didzis's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17619435/892313), I would make a separate data frame for the summary data that you want to display per facet.

```
library("plyr")
cns.annotate <- ddply(cns, .(Name), summarize, y.int=mean(Days[Type=="Completed"]))
```

then pass this data frame to `geom_hline`.

```
qplot(Date, data=cns, 
      geom="bar", binwidth = 1, 
      fill=Type, facets = Name ~ .) +
  geom_hline(data=cns.annotate, aes(yintercept=y.int))
```

or in ggplot rather than qplot syntax:

```
ggplot(cns, aes(x=Date)) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill=Type), binwidth=1) +
  geom_hline(data=cns.annotate, aes(yintercept=y.int)) +
  facet_grid(Name ~ .)
```