# Varying geom_hline for each facet_wrap plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

For each of the nine plots, I am trying to create two horizontal lines of the same color as "Method" where the y-intercept is the value of "Probability of Go" (ignore that these are not valid probabilities) when the "true landmark" is 0.65. For example, the top left plot would have a blue horizontal line at about y=6.25 and a red horizontal line at about y=5.2. Is there a simple way to do this without manually specifying the y-intercept for each of the 9 plots and for each of the 2 methods? My code right now is as follows:

```
true_landmark=seq(0.15,0.85,by=0.05);pt=6;theta=0.65
L=length(true_landmark)
type <- rep(c(rep("Exponential",L*2),rep("Log-Normal",L*2),rep("Weibull",L*2)),3)
method <- rep(c(rep("Landmark PFS",L),rep("RMST",L)),3*3)
n <- c(rep(20,L*2*3),rep(30,L*2*3),rep(40,L*2*3))
value <- replicate(18,cumsum(runif(15)))
landmark <- rep(true_landmark,2*3*3)  
df <- data.frame(type,method,n,value,landmark)
df$n <- factor(df$n,labels=c(expression(n==20),expression(n==30),expression(n==40)))
df$type <- factor(df$type,
                  labels=c("Exponential",
                           expression(paste("Log-Normal (",sigma==1,")")),
                           expression(paste("Weibull (",k==0.5,")"))))

ggplot(df, aes(landmark,value,color=method)) +
  geom_line(alpha=0.5)+
  geom_point(shape=19,alpha=0.5)+
  geom_blank()+
  scale_x_continuous(name =paste("True Landmark PFS at", pt, "Months"), breaks=seq(true_landmark[1],true_landmark[length(true_landmark)], 0.1))+
  ylab(label="Probability of Go")+
  geom_vline(xintercept = theta, color="black", linetype="dashed")+
  #geom_text(aes(x=theta-0.02, label=paste("Target value =", theta), y=0.30), angle=90, size=4, color="black")+
  facet_grid(n~type,labeller=label_parsed)+
  guides(color=guide_legend(title="Method"))+
  theme(plot.caption=element_text(hjust=0))+
  labs(caption=paste("Go: Posterior prob (True PFS/RMST at", pt, "month > target|data)", ">", P_T,"\nDashed line indicates target landmark PFS/RMST value"))
```

[image]

Comment: Do these answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50980134/display-a-summary-line-per-facet-rather-than-overall or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54244009/different-geom-hline-for-each-facet-of-ggplot or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17619068/add-variable-geom-hline-to-all-facets-of-a-barplot

Comment: Since `0.65` is an actual value in your dataset, you can do `geom_hline(data = subset(df, landmark == 0.65), aes(yintercept = value, colour = method))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have made things a bit more difficult for yourself by leaving `value` as an array outside of the data frame (notice that although you include it when making `df`, as an array it just creates a bunch of columns called X1, X2, etc). You can solve the problem like this:

```r
ggplot(df, aes(landmark, value, color = method)) +
  geom_line(alpha = 0.5)+
  geom_point(shape = 19, alpha = 0.5) +
  geom_blank() +
  geom_hline(data = df[df$landmark == 0.65,],
             aes(yintercept = value[df$landmark == 0.65], color = method)) +
  scale_x_continuous(name = paste("True Landmark PFS at", pt, "Months"), 
                     breaks = seq(true_landmark[1], 
                                  true_landmark[length(true_landmark)], 0.1)) +
  ylab(label="Probability of Go") +
  geom_vline(xintercept = theta, color = "black", linetype = "dashed") +
  facet_grid(n~type,labeller = label_parsed)+
  guides(color = guide_legend(title = "Method")) +
  theme(plot.caption = element_text(hjust = 0)) +
  labs(caption = paste("Go: Posterior prob (True PFS/RMST at", pt, 
                      "month > target|data)", ">",
                      "\nDashed line indicates target landmark PFS/RMST value"))
```

[image]